# How to filter results in mongodb based on an arithmetic expression that depends on the input?

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a collection with entries like so:

```
{_id: "foo" lng: -98.21 lat: 77.131 }
{_id: "foo" lng: -100.12 lat: 770.313 }
{_id: "foo" lng: -98.32 lat: 772.123 }
```

where lng and lat correspond to the longitude and latitude.

I want to return only the entries that are within a certain radius of the the input longitude and latitude. So that would mean that for radius R, sqrt((inputLatiude - docLatitude)^2 + (inputLongitude - docLonguitude)^2) < R. 
I don't want to return all the documents with an added field that tells me whether it's within R or not. I want to return only the fields that match the condition.
How do I query this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [$near](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) here to do so. However `$near` requires a [2dsphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/) index built which currently seems like you don't have one as the document structure does not match the required structure.

So what do you have to do?

1. Restructure your document so the `lng` and `lat` fields could be 2dsphere indexed:

```
{
   _id: "foo",
   loc : { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -98.21, 77.131 ] },
}
```

2. Build such index on the field `loc`.
3. Use `$near` to query:

```
db.collection.find(
   {
     loc:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ inputLng, inputLat ] },
            $maxDistance: R
          }
       }
   }
)
```